# Getting Recent Page feeds? Facebook Graph API / FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get recent page feeds from Graph Api or from FQL ?

Eg: Once you login then the feeds appear on this URL - https://www.facebook.com/pages/feed

Many thanks,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that this isn't properly possible, one can get feeds and then filter it on the basis of type=page and then use it accordingly or individually access {pageid}/feed to get the feeds of a single page. Hope it helps someone else.

Regards,

Reno Jones