# How to GET Recent Status Updates on Facebook Page Using Facebook Graph Search API?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

Similar to [Getting Recent Page feeds? Facebook Graph API / FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757063/getting-recent-page-feeds-facebook-graph-api-fql) and [Getting Facebook Status updates with JSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927430/getting-facebook-status-updates-with-json) I would like to do a GET request using Facebook's Graph API, and insert that data into a page.  Using the search API, I am able to retrieve information about the page like locale, description, and website, but there is no status update/post update included in the resulting JSON.

How can I retrieve the latest status updates/posts from a given page using Facebook's public Graph API?

Comment: Why would you use search API for retrieving recent updates on a **given/particular** page. Why not query it directly from the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it **is** possible to do this, but you need to generate an access token (for the page).  To do this, you will need to have admin rights to the page in question.  So for me, I had to request from that the page make me an admin (point them to the "Manage Admin Roles" dropdown on the page).

Next, you will need to generate an access token.  Go here [Facebook API Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and click on the "GET Access Token" button the right.  Select the `manage_pages` role **only**.

The final URL should look something like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/statuses?access_token=BAACEdE...`

Here is the javascript function I used to test my URL (you could also just navigate there on your browser):

```
function populateFacebookUpdates() {
        var pageID = "mycompanypage",
            accessToken = "BAACEdE...";
        var postsURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageID + "/statuses?access_token=" + accessToken;

        $.ajax({
            url: postsURL,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data)
            {
                console.log("Successfully retrieved Facebook data");
                console.dir(data);
            },
            error: function(status) {
                console.log("Facebook data could not be retrieved.  Failed with a status of " + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

The data returned in JSON was what I wanted.  Also, note that the retrieval would work on any browser/machine/IP (it does expire, however).  I would just caution against putting the entire URL inside a client-side javascript file for obvious security reasons...

Comment: It turns out that ``statuses`` is just fine for my purposes.  Without using the PHP SDK, I was able to access my page's most recent posts (including shared links, status updates, etc.).  To do this, I simply did a ``GET`` on the following URL: ``https://graph.facebook.com/[pageID]/feed?access_token=[appIDhere]|[appSecretHere]``.  Note the ``|`` delimiter to separate both of the credentials.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Note that using `/{pageID}/statuses?access_token=...` returns this **error** with recent versions of the API: `(#12) statuses field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`.

Answer (score 0):

Status's is a connection and not a field as per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). As far as I know only field information can be retrieved via the search API. If you want statuses you'll have to get the page Id from your search and then query for that pages statuses using the call below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/statuses
```

Comment: It won't work for me.  Still need authentication: ```{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}``` Would I need to use oAuth then, to authorize the server retrieving the data before doing the GET?

Comment: Try https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/statuses?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}. You can quickly generate an access token using the graph explorer tool http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=554718794%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: Yes, but the access token is temporary.  How would I generate an access token without an app or an app ID?  From reading the PHP SDK documentation, it seems I need to have an app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ - would I need to have the server "log in" as me to generate an access token which can be used repeatedly for each session?

Comment: That's somewhat of another topic. But access_token are typically programatically generated as they are needed. As far as I know you do need to set up a Facebook app to programatically generate an access_token.

Comment: If your initial question has been answered please mark the green check to the left of the question so other users can see there's an accepted answer.

Comment: It hasn't been answered yet.  It seems to me that you **do** need an access token in order to perform these tasks (see my post below).  I think I'm going to try using PHP to make the GET request, and then check the response to see if there is an authentication error; if there is, I will generate a new token... like here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: Note that using `/{pageID}/statuses?access_token=...` returns this **error** with recent versions of the API: `(#12) statuses field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`.